# Data not showing on Android Pie 9.0

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-8.0-oreo, android-9.0-pie, android-8.1-oreo

After I updated my phone from Android Oreo 8.0 to Android Pie 9.0, I no longer can get data from MySQL database using HttpUrlConnection.

I try with emulator Android Oreo 8.0 and the data is displayed. However, when I try with emulator Android Pie 9.0, the data is not displayed. Please help me.

Comment: Are you using http instead of https?If you are using http then look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Recently had the same issue for Android 9, but I had to use some URLs for different screens. So I added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to Manifest and it worked, but we didn't want to compromise the security of the whole app for this. So the fix was in changing links from HTTP to https.But if you had to use only http to communicate with your app then here is your solution.

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/security_config"
```

Add this in the Xml

```
<network-security-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"/>
<debug-overrides>
<trust-anchors>
<certificates src="system" />
<certificates src="user" />
</trust-anchors>
</debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Does it mean that if my REST API is not secured with  HTTPS, the app won't work on Android 9 devices?

Comment: I got crashes when I used the HTTP over https in pie devices then I researched about it and I came to know about cleartext traffic Permission for pie devices.

Comment: Thank you so much @g.brahma Datta. The data is displayed and now I can continue with other development before submit my assignment :)

Comment: When an app communicates with servers using a cleartext network traffic, such as HTTP, it could raise a risk of eavesdropping and tampering of content. Third parties can inject unauthorized data or leak information about the users. That is why developers are encouraged to a secure traffic only, such as HTTPS. @Rakhi Dhavale

Comment: That's awesome @WeiHangTan.I am happy that you didn't get stuck before implementing this in your code.

Comment: I'm aware of why we must use HTTPS , but I've not understood if it  works on Oreo why it doesn't work on Android 9 Pie ???

Comment: Your solution will surely work , but there has to be a reason on why it doesn't work on Android 9 if I use http instead of https

Answer (score 0):

**If your app targets Android 9 or higher, the `isCleartextTrafficPermitted()` method       returns false by default.**

If your app needs to enable cleartext for specific domains, you must explicitly set cleartextTrafficPermitted to true for those domains in your app's Network Security Configuration.

[Framework Security changes in Android 9 that improve your app's security](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28)