# java.net.UnknownHostException Unable to resolve host “http://www.sanjarcreation.com/”: No address associated with hostname

Tags: android

On Latest 9.0 pie+ Oppo OnePlus Getting this error only over internet connection but works fine on Wifi but when I refresh page for 2 to three times then it loads.

```
   public void parseHomeCategorydata(Context context){
        RequestQueue requestQ = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Const.Base_Url+"manage/api/p_category/all/?X-Api-Key="+Const.API_KEY+"&start=0&limit=100&field=shop_id&filter="+Const.Shop_id+"&parent=0" , null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("data");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("p_category");
                    homeCategoryRecModelArrayList = Parser.parseHomeCategoryList(jsonArray);
                    homeCategoryRecAdapter = new HomeCategoryRecAdapter(context , homeCategoryRecModelArrayList);
                    recyclerViewCategory.setAdapter(homeCategoryRecAdapter);
//                    parseSliderData(context);

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if(error.getMessage()==null){
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to retrieve data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(context, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                }
        );
        requestQ.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using http or https in the Url @suyash?

Comment: I am using http://

Comment: This might be the problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/55534085/7352857

Comment: ok I will try this

Comment: Have you tried that @suyash?

Comment: It doesn't worked and all solution provided here doesn't worked mobile is OnePlus 6T

Comment: Can you post the error log @suyash?

Comment: And don't show the Url which you have posted in the question just a suggestion bro

Comment: Access denied finding property “vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval" this is not my phone its one of client's this is the log message I got yesterday

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing or working with Pie then you need to give support of `https` instead of `http`.

If you don't have https URL, for now, you can add bellow line in your application tag from the manifest file

```
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Full code

```
<application
        android:name=".ApplicationClass"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_config"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/main_theam"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">
```

Also if you are using google map then please add bellow line in your application tag(inside tag)

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: It doesn't worked and all solution provided here doesn't worked mobile is OnePlus 6T

Comment: If you have tried and it's not working then you need to change your domain https.

Answer (score 0):

create a xml file network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://www.sanjarcreation.com/</domain>
</domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

then add this to application tag in manifest :

```
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Comment: It doesn't worked and all solution provided here doesn't worked mobile is OnePlus 6T

Answer (score 0):

I Recently had the same issue for Android 9, but I had to use some URLs for different screens. So I added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to Manifest and it worked, but we didn't want to compromise the security of the whole app for this. So the fix was in changing links from HTTP to https.But if you had to use only http to communicate with your app then here is your solution.

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/security_config"
```

Add this in the Xml

```
<network-security-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"/>
<debug-overrides>
<trust-anchors>
<certificates src="system" />
<certificates src="user" />
</trust-anchors>
</debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: It doesn't worked and all solution provided here doesn't worked mobile is OnePlus 6T